# Difference between "margin-left", and "left" (or "margin-right", and "right")

Tags: css

What is the difference between 
`margin-left: 10px;` and `position: relative; left: 10px;`?

It seems to produce the same result

Answer (score 55, accepted):

When you move something with `position:relative` you're not actually moving the space it takes up on the page, just where it is displayed.

An easy way to test this is to use a simple structure like this:

```
<div id = "testbox">
  <img src = "http://www.dummyimage.com/300x200" id = "first">
  <img src = "http://www.dummyimage.com/300x200" id = "second">
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```css
img{ display:block; }
#first{ margin-top:50px; }
```

versus this CSS:

```css
img{display:block;}
#first{position:relative; top:50px;}
```

You'll see that the first moves everything down 50px while the second only moves the first image down (which means it will overlap the second image).

Edit: you can check it out in action here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/PKqMT/5/

Comment out the `position:relative;` and `top:100px;` lines and uncomment the `margin-top` line and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Good answer.. :)

Answer (score 62):

The simplest way I can explain it is that `margin-left` moves the element itself, whereas `left` (with `position: relative`) pushes other elements away. Although that's not, perhaps the clearest description.

With pictures, though:

```
            +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
            |                                                                                          |
            |              +------------------------------------------------------------+              |
            |              |                                                            |              |
            |              |              +------------------------------+              |              |
            |              |              |                              |              |              |
  position  |              |              |                              |              |              |
<--Left---->|<---margin--->|<---padding-->|<------------width----------->|<---padding-->|<---margin--->|
            |              |              |                              |              |              |
            |              |              +------------------------------+              |              |
            |              |                                                            |              |
            |              +------------------------------------------------------------+              |
            +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

With `position: absolute` left also serves to define the distance between the element itself and the left boundary of whatever object the element is positioned against.

Comment: Clearest explanation I've found! double thanks for the picture!

Comment: How did you draw that "picture"? I can't believe that you put symbol by symbol

Comment: @chill: from memory, I really was that bored at the time >.<

Comment: Didn't you said the opposite ? I tried the below answer and the `margin-left`  pushes other elements away while the `left` just overlay the other elements

Answer (score 0):

I can only suppose it is there for other positions with margins. i.e.:

```
margin-left: 5px;
position: inherited; left: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider any given block element (a DIV for example) as a box. `position:relative;` makes the box's position on the page relative to the element it is nested inside (another DIV for example) and `left:10px;` moves the box 10 pixels to the right (AWAY from the left).

Now `margin-left: 10px;` has nothing to do with that and just creates a margin (an invisible power field if you prefer :P) on the left of the box, which makes it move if there's another fixed element stuck on its left.