# left v/s margin-left and CSS: position

Tags: html, css

I am playing around to make an HTML/CSS carousel.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="d1" class="box"><p>DIV#1</p></div>
            <div id="d2" class="box"><p>DIV#2</p></div>
            <div id="d3" class="box"><p>DIV#3</p></div>
            <div id="d4" class="box"><p>DIV#4</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    float: left;
}

#container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 144px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 140px;
    width: 555px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}

#d1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#d2 {
    background-color: red;
}

#d3 {
    background-color: green;
}

#d4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/97jhB/.
I intend to add javascript controls and provisions for left/right buttons later.
First, I just want to learn conceptually how it works.

I am trying to get the carousel 'effect' by playing with the wrapper's `left`.
If I go on decreasing the wrapper's `left`, I will be able to see the boxes successively.

I have a couple of questions:

1. If I don't set the wrapper's `position` to `relative`, changes made to it's `left` do not take effect. Why is that so? Isn't the wrapper supposed to be `relative` by default?
2. If I play around with the wrapper's `margin-left` instead of `left`, it seems to work as desired.
   What is better between these two approaches: playing with `left` or playing with `margin-left`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign the ***`position:relative`*** CSS declaration to a div, you're not actually moving the space it takes up on the page, just where it is displayed.

However the **default position is `static` for any html element** if not specified explicitly.

```
position: static;
```

Check out this link on SO for a very complete explanation of the **margin-left v/s left** difference

[Difference between margin-left and left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859801/difference-between-margin-left-and-left)

Comment: No, but you certainly did not up vote my answer and yours is very similar to mine.

Comment: Coming back to your question. It's the same. Just a different way of putting it. EG 2+2 = 4   OR 2+2=3+1

Comment: Ok. I still suspect that you are suspecting me. So il upvote u. Now you will see that i did not downvote you

Comment: @AnaMaria thanks for the answer and the SO link.. i got the difference between the two..

Answer (score 4):

Because only `relative`, `absolute` and `fixed` positioning use `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` to define their locations relative to the current context they are in.

Fixed is relative to the viewport, absolute is taken out of the normal page flow and relative to the first parent with a CSS position set on it, and relative is just [relative to the nearest block-level ancestor](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning).

`static` is the default position and uses `margin-left`, `margin-right`, etc to position the element relative to other elements in the page flow, within the nearest block-level ancestor.

Also, be aware that position:fixed does not work as expected on [older mobile devices](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed).

MDN has [great documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on this subject.

Comment: Actually `relative` uses those properties to shift the element on the basis of its position.

Comment: @HashemQolami I updated to give more information..although the MDN link is more than thorough.

Comment: Thank you guys, just was frustrating that someone downvoted for selfish reasons.

Comment: It happens. I have stopped looking the +/- count long back.

Answer (score 0):

1. Static is the default, and the best thing to do is to have the wrapper `relative` and the items `absolute`, this way overflowing items won't go to the bottom (~ won't create new lines)... You'll have to remove `float:left` if you want to follow this path.
2. It's probably better to use left (or right if RTL), what if you want some margin between that your carousel slides, think of the scenario where you have more than one visible item.