# CSS position doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a picture of goldfish in a page, but it doesn't move when I change the values of the position

```
#goldfish {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 300px;
    right: 400px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
```

its positioned on the top left of the page and I can't move it anywhere else

I can only use CSS/HTML and Javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Mobile App 1</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../images/circle180.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,inital-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    canvas {
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    #goldfish {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 300px;
        right: 400px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    #star {
        position: fixed;
        top: 425px;
        left: 250px;
        right: 200px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    #silverfish {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        right: 100px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    body {
        position: fixed;
        background-image: url("http://i68.tinypic.com/2ijrpt4.png");
        background-size: 1000px 600px;
    }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://class.arts.ucsb.edu/~art102/includes/p5/p5.js"></script>
    <script>
    var r, g, b;
    var goldfishobject;
    var xvalue = 0;
    var yvalue = 0;
    var zvalue = 0;
    var silverfisheobject;

    function setup() {

        goldfishobject = document.getElementById("goldfish");
        silverfishobject = document.getElementById("silverfish");

    }

    function draw() {
        xvalue = rotationX
        yvalue = rotationY
        zvalue = rotationZ
        subx = rotationY;
        suby = rotationZ;
        subz = rotationX;
        goldfishobject.style.top = xvalue + "px";
        goldfishobject.style.left = yvalue + "px";
        goldfishobject.style.right = zvalue + "px";
        silverfishobject.style.top = subx + "px";
        silverfishobject.style.left = suby + "px";
        silverfishobject.style.right = subz + "px";
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="goldfish">
      <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/t8lt6t.png" width="200">
    </span>
    <span id="star">
      <img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2hrhkj8.png" width="150">
    </span>
    <span id="silverfish">
      <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/33k82zl.png" width="150">
    </span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please share your html code....

Comment: If the image is `50px`, What's the sense in using both `left` and `right`?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Please do not share your code in comment, update that in your question and the html code.

Comment: @Haytham You can edit the question and create a snippet `<>` - using relevant HTML and CSS - that shows us the problem.

Comment: Updated, it's in the first part, none of the images move when changing values

Comment: @Haytham Does  changing the `top` value doesn't work as well ? Or only moving the images left or right doesn't work?

Comment: fyi, you have error in your javascript. but that's unrelated to this question so

Comment: As far as I can see your CSS code works fine

Comment: Top doesn't work too

Comment: Help, why nothing is moving is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use margin and it will work.

```
    #goldfish {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: @Haytham you dont have use margin, you are already positioning the element using absolute positioning.

Comment: This is not correct. with absolute positioning you can use left, top , right or bottom. You were not able to see the changes because the positioning you gave was very less. you could have increased and it could have worked. You don't need absolute positioning if you are using margins which is again not the correct way to position elements in the first place

Comment: i suggest reviewing the two there is a difference.  To say that this answer is incorrect is just plain wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859801/difference-between-margin-left-and-left

Answer (score 0):

The css works fine, you just need to change the position values. I don't see anything wrong here.

For example:

```
#goldfish {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Mobile App 1</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../images/circle180.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,inital-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    canvas {
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    #goldfish {
        position: absolute;
        top: 200px;
        left: 300px;
        right: 400px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    #star {
        position: fixed;
        top: 425px;
        left: 250px;
        right: 200px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    #silverfish {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        right: 100px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    
    body {
        position: fixed;
        background-image: url("http://i68.tinypic.com/2ijrpt4.png");
        background-size: 1000px 600px;
    }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://class.arts.ucsb.edu/~art102/includes/p5/p5.js"></script>
    <script>
    var r, g, b;
    var goldfishobject;
    var xvalue = 0;
    var yvalue = 0;
    var zvalue = 0;
    var silverfisheobject;

    function setup() {

        goldfishobject = document.getElementById("goldfish");
        silverfishobject = document.getElementById("silverfish");

    }

    function draw() {
        xvalue = rotationX
        yvalue = rotationY
        zvalue = rotationZ
        subx = rotationY;
        suby = rotationZ;
        subz = rotationX;
        goldfishobject.style.top = xvalue + "px";
        goldfishobject.style.left = yvalue + "px";
        goldfishobject.style.right = zvalue + "px";
        silverfishobject.style.top = subx + "px";
        silverfishobject.style.left = suby + "px";
        silverfishobject.style.right = subz + "px";
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="goldfish">
      <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/t8lt6t.png" width="200">
    </span>
    <span id="star">
      <img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2hrhkj8.png" width="150">
    </span>
    <span id="silverfish">
      <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/33k82zl.png" width="150">
    </span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can move the goldfish else where you want. Left position works for positive values but right and bottom works for negative values.

```
#goldfish {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    right: -400px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    }
```